# Graph database design: Should I add relationships, or just traverse

Tags: graph, database-design, neo4j, graph-databases

I have recently started exploring graph databases and Neo4J, and would like to work with my own data. At the moment I've hit some confusion. I've created an example image to illustrate my issue. In terms of efficiency, I'm wondering which option is better (and I want to get it right now in early days before I start handling larger amounts).

[image: Illustration]

Option A: Using only the blue relationships, I can work out whether things are related to, or come under, the Ancient group. This process will be done many many times, however it is unlikely to be more than ~6 generations.

Option B: I implement the red relationships, so that it is much faster to work out if young structures belong to the Ancient group.

I'm trying not to use Labels in this scenario, as I'm trying to use labels for a specific purpose to simplify my life (linking structures across seperate networks), and I'm not sure if I should have a label to represent a node that already exists.

In summary, I'm wondering whether adding a whole new bunch of relationships, whilst taking more space, is worth it, or whether traversing to find all relatives is such a simple/inexpensive task that it isn't worth doing so. Or alternatively, both options are viable and this isn't a real issue at all. Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd go with Option A. One of the strengths of Neo4j is that it traverses relationships very efficiently and quickly, and so, there is no need to materialise relationships (sometimes, relationships are materialised in complex and/or extremely large graphs, but this is not your case).

Not sure why you don't want to use labels? Labels serve to group nodes into sets of the same type, and are also index backed- this makes it much faster to find the starting point of your query (index lookup over full database scan).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'll go with Option A. For labels I'm reserving them for a specific use which will be grouping things by many kinds of topics. Whilst the example I've given, grouping nodes would have been used to show they are the same family. I thought life would be simpler if I keep topics as labels, and families as relationships/nodes.